# Is it possible in Vaadin to test the validity of just one field with binder?

Tags: vaadin

Is it possible in Vaadin to test the validity of just one field with binder?

binder.validate() checks all fields. I need to just probe/test the validity of one field, and then only later on validate the whole binder.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it should be possible, you need just to store reference to the binding

```
Binding<BeanType, ValueType> binding = binder.forField(..)..
binding.validate();
```

Comment: Perfect - thank you.